# How to model JSON dictionaries?

Tags: json, data-structures, dictionary, model

I am currently working on a project where I have to document (in a report) the data structures that are being exchanged between a client and a server. The format I use is JSON.

I was thinking about using a JSON dump with placeholder data, but it quickly gets messy as there are quite a few imbricated dictionaries.

Is there a standard way to model it? How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I've told people that its basically a dynamically typed and nested dictionaries in python, but somebody who uses static languages only will still be confused.

I took a quick glance at http://json.org to see how they do it, but they get a little too complicated and technical, which isn't great for communication.

looks like wikipedia has the right idea: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON.

my favourite part is their comparing the same structure between JSON and XML. I'm going to use this next time XML comes up at work.